# Translation from C/C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++, translation, dllexport

I am really stuck here. I hope somebody can help me.
How do I translate this function to C#?

```
void __declspec(dllexport) __cdecl test(float *avrSwap, int *aviFAIL, char *accInfile, char *avcOutname, char *avcMsg)
```

Comment: you want call this c++ function in C#?

Comment: I dont want to compile it first i C++. I want to call the equivalent c# function.

Comment: make an `unsafe` block and call the function. shouldn't that work?

Comment: So this function is a in C++ DLL? if so, you need use pinvoke to Call it in C#

Comment: @ManojAwasthi could you give me an example of an unsafe call?

Comment: @Matt pinvoke requires to compile it in c++, right?

Comment: @Medinoc, well avrSwap is both an input and an output, aviFAIL is an output, accInfile and avcOutname are both input's and avcMsg is an output.

Comment: All single values? Or some are arrays?

Comment: @Medinoc avrSWAP is an array, aviFAIL is a single value, accInfile is an array, avcOutname is an array and avcMsg is an array

Comment: Would this work? unsafe static void test(float* avrSwap, int* aviFAIL, char* accInfile, char* avcOutname, char* avcMsg) {...}

Comment: @Medinoc Sorry, all array are 1024

Comment: So if I got it right, `avrSwap` is an in/out array of 1024 float, `aviFAIL` is an output array of 1024 int, `accInfile` and `acvOutname` are input C strings, and `avcMsg` is an output string buffer of size 1024?

Comment: @Medinoc No. avrSwap is an in/out array of 1024 float, aviFAIL is an single int output, accInfile and acvOutname are input C strings, and avcMsg is an output string buffer of size 1024

Answer (score 1):

```
[DllImport("dllname", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint="test")]
private static void Test(
    [In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst=1024)] float[] avrSwap,
    out int aviFAIL,
    [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string accInfile,
    [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string avcOutname,
    [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)], StringBuilder avcMsg
);

//Wrapper that correctly initializes the StringBuilder to its rightful size.
//It's quite stupid that according to the P/Invoke help, 
//StringBuilder parameters don't support SizeConst.
public static void WrapTest(float[] avrSwap, out int aviFAIL, string accInfile, string avcOutname, out string avcMsg)
{
    StringBuilder sbAvcMsg = new StringBuilder(1024);
    Test(avrSwap, out aviFail, accInfile, avcOutname, sbAvcMsg);
    avcMsg = sbAvcMsg.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, as mentioned above "I dont want to compile it first in C++. I want to call the equivalent c# function." The reason for this is, that in my application the c++ function will change at run time. C# is easy to compile internally at runtime, while c++ can (only?) be compiled at runtime using msbuild.exe (and others). However, the solution I am looking for is an internal compiler, and I have not be able to find an internal c++ compiler.

Comment: Then, its parameters will probably be the same as `WrapTest`'s.